# Set a web link to a "word" in a VBA email

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

If this email does not display properly, please click **here**.

I would like to be able to have the person in the email click on the word "here" and then it will take them to a website.

This is what I have bee using but it just puts the full link into the email.

```
mymsg = "<HTML><BODY>"
mymsg = "If this email does not display properly, please click " & "<A href=http://us.localnews.com/ov?mailing=3TVGZMLJ-WDS49&m2u=3TVGZMLK-3TVGZMLJ-12Z630I>URL Text</A>"
mymsg = mymsg & "</BODY></HYML>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Keep it simple, no need for the `HTML/BODY` tags*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .HTMLBody = "If this email does not display properly, please click " & _
                    "<A href=https://stackoverflow.com/>" & _
                    "Here</A>"
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

*Make sure you are using `HTMLBody` Property*

***[MSDN - HTMLBody Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa171418(v=office.11))***

*Returns or sets a String representing the HTML body of the specified item. The HTMLBody property should be an HTML syntax string. Read/write.*

Comment: Sadly, it is still emailing the full link.

Comment: @Jay are you using `HTMLBody ` ? can you post your code please so i can run test

Comment: I apologize, I was not using the HTMLBody. Thank you