Add a clickable link, within the email text body, to a file location
I have Excel VBA code that sends an email.
Data is pulled from various cells to populate the body of text within the email.
I want to add a clickable link, within the email text body, to the file location that is located in cell AM22.
Sub email_from_excel_basic()

Dim emailapplication As Object
Dim emailitem As Object
Dim link As String

Set emailapplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailitem = emailapplication.createitem(0)

' build the email
emailitem.to = Range("Handover!D9").Value
emailitem.Subject = "Handover Created."
emailitem.Body = "Handover created to carry out the following:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL17").Value & "    " & Range("Handover!AM17").Value & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL18").Value & "  " & Range("Handover!AM18").Value & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL19").Value & "  " & Range("Handover!AM19").Value & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL20").Value & "  " & Range("Handover!AM20").Value & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL21").Value & "  " & Range("Handover!AM21").Value & vbNewLine & Range("Handover!AL22").Value & "  " & Range("Handover!AM22").Value

' send the email
emailitem.send

Set emailitem = Nothing
Set emailapplication = Nothing

End Sub

I tried adding the range but it populates the text from cell AM22 not as a link.

Please do not post pictures of code. No one can copy/paste it when you use an image.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Welcome to the board.  As the previous two comments have said..... there's an Edit button at the bottom of your question so you can update it with the code pasted as text.  At the top of the edit box is a button labelled { }  this will format the pasted code as code.

Please, try translating this part "to add a clickable link within the email text body that would take them to the file location that is located in cell AM22". What do you mean by it? What are you expecting to be the behavior of that link clicking? Do you attach the workbook, too? I cannot see it. I suppose that you send the email to somebody else. What path do you imagine can be used to match his workbook path, supposing that it exists? Do you want the link to be active for you, before sending the mail, or for the one receiving it? Where the workbook address to be? Is it a shared location?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60893141/4539709

Instead of using plain text Body property, use HTMLBody and populate its value with HTML data that includes <a> links.
Also keep in mind that the location of the file that the link points to must be accessible by the intended recipient - it cannot point to a local file on the machine where the script is running. If that is not the case, consider adding files as attachments instead (emailitem.Attachments.Add).
